# Datetimepicker broken first time in node webkit application

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, node-webkit

I am using datetimepicker for showing calender in my application it works fine in developer  mode but in build version it shows incorrect time in first time on calender but after second click and onwards its working fine. can you help me where i have done mistake or is there any jquery confliction

```
<div class="input-group date" id="dateinput">
                    <input type='text' id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Delivery Date" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                      </span>
                    </span> 
</div>


$('#dateinput').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YY | hh:mm A', showToday:true});
```

Comment: <div class="input-group date" id="dateinput">
                    <input type='text' id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Delivery Date" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                      </span>
                    </span> 
</div>